# Regex replace all match with symbol with same length

Tags: java, regex

My application currently logs sensitive information, which I need to mask.

A current log line looks like:

```
<Unable to fetch user info combination of dob=[20001231] and pan=[ABCD1234Z]
```

But should be changed to something like

```
<Unable to fetch user info combination of dob=******** and pan=********>
```

I tried to mask this using

```
str.replaceAll("\\[.*?\\]", "*")
```

but it changed it to:

`<Unable to fetch user info combination of dob=* and pan=*>`

How can I preserve the quantity of characters when masking characters between square brackets?

Comment: Your current solution seems better to me. You want to hide everything about the sensitive information, **including the length**.

Comment: If you want more `*`, just give it more `*`. :D

Comment: i need better then this, My dob have 8 char's so that i need masking like ******** instead of *

Comment: Read my comment. It's better that you don't reveal the length.

Comment: Why would you want to give hints about the length of the string?

Comment: @shmosel raises a good point. If you don't want something in your log, why log it? Maybe it would be better to make the log message a generic `Unable to fetch user info` and avoid the need to redact the sensitive information in the first place?

Comment: @shmosel, @matt, Logging of sensitive data makes sense because pan value might be null for some case. In this case log will have value `null`. See my proposed answer.

Comment: Logging is supposed to be as fast as possible. Parsing log informations with a Regex seems like a really bad idea. It would be better to work to not log this information at all instead of hiding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done in one line:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?=[^\\[]+]).", "*");
```

See [live regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/JDJRkUoa7y) and/or [live Java demo](http://ideone.com/O72LJL).

This preserves the square brackets. To omit them from the result, use this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\[?(?=[^\\[]*]).]?", "*");
```

See [live Java demo](http://ideone.com/djK7fg).

Answer (score 2):

You can manipulate Pattern and Matcher to do this. For example like this:

```
String log = "<Unable to fetch user info combination of dob=[20001231] and pan=[ABCD1234Z]>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[.*?\\]");
Matcher  matcher = pattern.matcher(log);
String match="";
while (matcher.find()){
    match=matcher.group();
    char[] symbols = new char[match.length()];
    Arrays.fill(symbols, '*');
    log = log.replace(match, new String(symbols));  
}
System.out.println(log);
```

Output:

```
<Unable to fetch user info combination of dob=******** and pan=********>
```

There might be some performance issue in the example above, but at least you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the similar questions here, for example this one: [Customising log4j logging for sensitive data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817956/customising-log4j-logging-for-sensitive-data). It proposes to override toString(). You can make the same thing here. Of course if you pan is String then it might be harder. You can wrap it to class Pan and create toString here:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
class Pan {
    private String value;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(value).map(x -> "***").orElse(null);
    }
}
```

It will prevent writing Pan everywhere in all log messages, not only in your particular one.

Using of toString:

```
Pan pan = new Pan();
pan.setValue("123456789");
log.error("<Unable to fetch user info combination of dob=[{}] and pan=[{}]>", dob, pan);
```